# How retain the original value if it is subtract to 'NULL'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a sample table here and I want to subtract the "items out" to the "items in" but it gives me a null which means there is no out in this items and I want the null should be the value of "items in".

```
|ItemCode | Qty |isIN|isOUT|
|---------|-----|----|-----|
|  1      |2    |  1 |  0  |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
|  2      |5    |  1 |  0  |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
|   3     | 1   |  1 |  0  |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
|   4     | 2   |  1 |  0  |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 10      | 14  |  1 | 0   |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 10      |  1  |  0 | 1   |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
|  10     |  1  |  0 |   1 |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 12      |   1 |1   | 0   |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 12      |   1 | 0  | 1   |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 13      |  1  | 1  | 0   |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 14      |   2 | 1  | 0   |
|---------|-----|----|-----|
| 14      | 1   |0   |1    |
```

My query is this.

```
SELECT i.ItemCode, Sum(i.Qty)-(select Sum(Qty) from INVENTORY where isOUT = 1 and i.ItemCode = ItemCode)as Qty
FROM INVENTORY i
WHERE isIN = 1
GROUP BY i.ItemCode
```

the result is this:

```
|ItemCode | Qty |
|---------|-----|
|  1      |NULL |
|---------|-----|
|  2      |NULL |
|---------|-----|
|   3     |NULL |
|---------|-----|
|   4     |NULL | 
|---------|-----|
| 10      | 12  | 
|---------|-----|
| 12      |   0 |
|---------|-----|
| 13      | NULL|
|---------|-----|
| 14      |   1 | 
|---------|-----|
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.  What results do you want?

Comment: do you have nulls in your db ? If so, you might need to add default values in the query (like 0). If not, probably is there's something wrong in your query

Comment: Hi Gordon im using sql server 2008

Comment: actually those null are the itemcode which doesnt have an items out. i want is there's no item out it should be Qty - 0 instead of Qty - Null becuase if its null it will give me results null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a sample table here and i want to subtract the "items out" to
>   the "items in"

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select i.ItemCode,
       sum(case when i.isIN = 1 then i.Qty
                when i.isOut = 1 then - i.Qty
           end)
from inventory i
group by i.ItemCode;
```

No subquery is needed at all.

Comment: Yes, this is it. it works. thanks a lot Gordon. im thinking a lot how to subtract while it can only be than in case. many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT i.ItemCode, Sum(ISNULL(i.Qty,0))-(select Sum(ISNULL(Qty,0)) from INVENTORY where isOUT = 1 and i.ItemCode = ItemCode)as Qty
FROM INVENTORY i
WHERE isIN = 1
GROUP BY i.ItemCode
```

Use

> ISNULL(column,value)

so if the value is null, it treats it as 0 (or whatever value you like)